# How can I remove the CustomerName validation from Hybris 1905 so when I create a Customer I can do it without name?

Tags: validation, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to take out the CustomerName constraint but I don't know how Can accomplish this with good practices, I tried from the backoffice but the Constraint group would not be able to update from backoffice, and try with some Impex but still got error. How can I accomplish this? Because Im getting the users from the SAP customer data cloud but cannot register them only with email and password because this constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you change the value of **Enabled** to **False**?

[image]

If yes, you should also click the **Reload validation engine** button (highlighted in the screenshot)

[image]